# All rails projects - Bundler is using a binstub that was created for a different gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

In all of my Rails projects, when I run rails s, I get the following output:

```
Bundler is using a binstub that was created for a different gem.
This is deprecated, in future versions you may need to `bundle binstub rails` to work around a system/bundle conflict.
```

I've seen solutions to deal with Projects, but could I have a system wide issue?

Comment: Did you try following the instructions in the message?

Comment: When I run the command I get: rails has no executables, but you may want one from a gem it depends on.
  railties has: rails
  bundler has: bundle, bundler

Answer (score 0):

this happened if you have both 3.x and 4.x in your system, or two version that have different bin name, in my system, I use 3.2.22, which  name is `railties` and 4.x bin name is rails, Rubygems will create a binstubs for gem at first install, so if you as I did install 4.x rails first, other 3.x project will have this message.
the last line of binstub file for rails 4.x is this:
    load Gem.bin_path('railties', 'rails', version)

while for 3.x is this
    load Gem.bin_path('rails', 'rails', version)

the warn message are come from line 344 of rubygems_integration.rb from bundler gem

```
def replace_bin_path(specs)
  gem_class = (class << Gem; self; end)
  redefine_method(gem_class, :bin_path) do |name, *args|
    exec_name = args.first

    return ENV["BUNDLE_BIN_PATH"] if exec_name == "bundle"

    spec = nil

    if exec_name
      spec = specs.find {|s| s.executables.include?(exec_name) }
      raise(Gem::Exception, "can't find executable #{exec_name}") unless spec
      unless spec.name == name
        warn "Bundler is using a binstub that was created for a different gem.\n" \
          "This is deprecated, in future versions you may need to `bundle binstub #{name}` " \
          "to work around a system/bundle conflict."
      end
    else
      spec = specs.find {|s| s.name == name }
      raise Gem::Exception, "no default executable for #{spec.full_name}" unless exec_name = spec.default_executable
    end

    gem_bin = File.join(spec.full_gem_path, spec.bindir, exec_name)
    gem_from_path_bin = File.join(File.dirname(spec.loaded_from), spec.bindir, exec_name)
    File.exist?(gem_bin) ? gem_bin : gem_from_path_bin
  end
end
```

so the solution is uninstall all rails

```
gem uninstall rails
```

remove the binstub file if still there

```
which rails
rm -rf path_of_rails
```

and install the version of rails you actually use

```
gem install rails -v 3.2.22
```

Comment: when typing gem install rails -v 3.2.6, Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
 this is the error